# Angular mix different [ngClass] expressions

Tags: css, angular

I would like to mix the `[ngClass]` Expressions in Angular, first I want to add an array of classes to my component and then I would also like to add a class based on a Boolean expression. 
I can add an array with `<li [ngClass]="item.status">` and I can add a class based on a Boolean expression with `<li [ngClass]="{active: item.active}">`

**Note:** item.status is an array like `item.status=['done', 'progressed']`

But how can I mix both styles? 
The following doesn't work because only the attribute is duplicate.
`<li [ngClass]="item.status" [ngClass]="{active: item.active}">`

Thanks in advance

Comment: i updated my answer little bit because i show your "**Note:**" there. please check it now.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you could not have [**`[ngClass]`**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) multiple time in same element you could use the combination  of [**`[ngClass]`**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) and  **`class`**. When use `class` in this way with interpolation then you could add several classes as well.  Try to use following way.

**E.g. HTML**

```
<li  class="t-size {{item.status.join(' ')}}" [ngClass]="{'active': item.active }">
```

**E.g. Component**

```js
 item = {
    status : ['done', 'progressed'],
    active: true
  }
```

**E.g. CSS**

```
.done{
  font-weight: bold;
}

.progressed{
  color:blue;
}

.t-size{
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.active{
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

<kbd>[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pievkv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)</kbd>

Hope this will help to you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use both as below:

```
<li [class]="item.status" [ngClass]="{active: item.active}">
```

You cannot use `ngClass` more than one time in the single element.

Comment: It almost worked, i just had to use ``[class]="item.status.join(' ')"`` because Angular seems to expect a string and not an array. This also doesn't add the class twice if it is given anywhere else.

Comment: @danielr1996 `item.status` should be a string, not an array, the code will break if you use `.join(' ')` on the string. In case of the array, you're right.

Comment: Well maybe i was unclear what datatype my variables are, indeed my variable is an array, i'll edit my question

Answer (score 0):

You can do `[class.myClass]="booleanExpression"`, but I don't recommend adding it together with `[ngClass]` because then you could have a class multiple times.

Instead I would recommend either making `[class.myClass]="booleanExpression"` for each and every class you use in that HTML-tag (keep in mind the `"booleanExpression"` can set/unset more than one class so it would not increase the lines of code in your .ts file, only in the template). Or I would make a getter method for `[ngClass]`:

`[ngClass]="liClasses"`

```
get liClasses(): string {
    const result = "";
    if (conditionOne) { result += " myClassOne"}
    if (conditionTwo) { result += " myClassTwo"}
    return result;
}
```

note that solution 1) is more perfomant as getter-methods get triggered on every change-detection and not only when conditionOne or conditionTwo changes.

Comment: The problem is, I don't know which classes might get set, the user of my component can add arbitrary class names that i cannot check.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code here your **app component** is

```
member = true;
paidAmount = true;
setMyClass() {
    let classes =  {
         member: this.someProperty,    
         paid: this.paidAmount, 
    };
    return classes;
}
```

*where **'member'** and **'paid'** is class name*

---

**and your template use this similar code**

```
<div class="myclass" [ngClass]="setMyClass()">Call to Action</div>
```